# Are there meaningful performance differences for declaring variables inside javascript class constructor vs a method called inside said constructor?

Tags: javascript, class, class-constructors

I'm really new to JS and stackoverflow but not new to coding so forgive me if this has already been answered somewhere.

The reason to do it the second way would only be to improve the 'neatness' of the class.  I'm wondering if there are performance trade-offs for readability by doing it that way.

To be more clear:

is there a performance loss from doing this:

```
class MyClass{
    constructor(args){
        this.UpdateClass(args);
    }
    UpdateClass(args){
        this.firstVar = this.GetFirstVar();
        this.secondVar = this.GetSecondVar(args);
    }
    GetFirstVar(){
        return 420;
    }
    GetSecondVar(args){
        return args.Cheesesteak;
    }
}
```

Instead of doing this:

```
class MyClass{
    constructor(args){
        this.firstVar = this.GetFirstVar();
        this.secondVar = this.GetSecondVar(args);
    }
    UpdateClass(args){
        this.firstVar = this.GetFirstVar();
        this.secondVar = this.GetSecondVar(args);
    }
    GetFirstVar(){
        return 420;
    }
    GetSecondVar(args){
        return args.Cheesesteak;
    }
}
```

My interpretation of reading Google's js style guide was that they should always declare class variables inside the constructor because it's more computationally expensive to declare class variables inside another method, but is that still the case when the class method defines and/or updates every class variable without exception.

Comment: Can you provide some real-world code, please? Most of the methods in this class look rather pointless, and saving a single line doesn't really make the class look "more neat"

Comment: Alright, sorry I typed it from memory.  I'll figure out how to edit it with changes.

Comment: "*My interpretation of reading Google's js style guide was that they should always declare class variables inside the constructor because it's more computationally expensive to declare class variables inside another method,*" where does it say that? As far as I'm aware, the style guide only mentions not to add fields after the constructor finishes. Calling a method from the constructor is still *before* it finishes.

Comment: I can't provide real world code, but in my particular application there are 20 methods called in the constructor to update 20 class variables so it saves something like 20 lines to do all the declarations inside the update method.  I'm just not familiar enough with how JS compiles to know whether or not this is causing excessive computations by creating the variables inside a method inside the constructor instead of just creating them inside the constructor directly... I personally can't see any difference but again I'm pretty ignorant of JS.

Comment: In the Google style guide I was referencing section 5.4.2 there is a "Tip" at the bottom that suggests not creating properties outside of the constructor.

Comment: @ajos2 A constructor that calls 20 methods sounds like there are other problems with your design.

Comment: The real code smell here are the methods `GetFirstVar` and `GetSecondVar` that don't use the instance (`this`) so they shouldn't be instance methods. Either just inline them, make them static, or even move that functionality to separate functions next to the class.

Comment: @ajos2 "*Properties should never be added to or removed from an instance after the constructor is finished,*" - again, calling a method *from the constructor* means it isn't finished yet. Control will return to it after the method is done.

Comment: @VLAZ, yea that does make sense, thank you.  That at least answers part of my question!

Comment: @Bergi, I think I understand what you are saying.  The idea for this class is to be a data object where a new, predefined set of data is passed in with args and each variable has some computation done from the passed in arg (in this case GetFirstVar and GetSecondVar).  In that case I still wouldn't be using the instance so I can keep them inside the class and remove the instance call (this)?  Thanks again for your input.

Comment: @ajos2 Is the data object meant to be mutable or immutable? Are there defaults that would be useful for an "empty object"? What kind of computation (heavy, side-effectful) are you doing? Does this computation always affect all properties at once? Is each new property value derived from the whole input, or only a (non-overlapping) part of it? That's why it makes sense to post your actual code here.

Comment: Btw, since you're asking "*Are there meaningful performance differences*" - how many instances of the class do you create and how often do you access them? Have you tried measuring the performance?

Comment: @Bergi, haha, yea I would prefer to post my code but I can't.  The object is meant to be mutable, the only useful values for an empty object would be 'null.'  Computation is done from an incoming data array <strings>.  Strings are converted to integer values, some are scaled by static float values, some are reconverted to strings and some are just reported as integer values.  Each data "chunk" (in this case the array) updates all values at the time it is recieved and there are never any partial updates.

Comment: @Bergi, I'm not sure how to measure the performance!  These objects will be created up to a few hundred times a second and will either update an existing object with a matching key or become a new object if no unique key is discovered.

Comment: @ajos2 "*Each data "chunk" updates all values*" - by update, do you mean overwrites? Or does it transform existing values? If the former, I would recommend not to use mutable objects if any mutation just replaces the entire object. If the latter, how is the first chunk treated specially?

Comment: @Bergi, I'm not sure the best etiquette for answering my own questions but I found site (jsfiddle) that I could test code snippets with and ran a few tests that show the second method is slower (which answers the initial question).  To your point: the objects are moved to a database if they are unique (the first time they get data) otherwise all of the values are overwritten each time data is recieved.  So I think you are right that they don't have to be mutable, is there a reason to make them mutable vs immutable in this case?  Thanks again!

Comment: @ajos2 If you don't make them mutable, you don't need the `UpdateClass` method and can avoid the code duplication. You would just have the constructor that initialises all the properties, potentially calling some static helper methods.

Comment: @Bergi that makes sense.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so thanks to @Bergi and @VLAZ for their help with this.  I ended up testing this code snippet in jsfiddle:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(data) {
    this.UpdateClass(data);
  }
  UpdateClass(data) {
    this.firstVar = this.GetFirstVar(data);
    this.secondVar = this.GetSecondVar(data);
  }

  GetFirstVar(data) {
    var first = data.slice(1, 4).join();
    return first;
  }
  GetSecondVar(data) {
    var cat = data.slice(2, 5);
    return cat;
  }
}

class MyClass2 {
  constructor(data) {
    this.firstVar = this.GetFirstVar(data);
    this.secondVar = this.GetSecondVar(data);
  }
  UpdateClass(data) {
    this.firstVar = this.GetFirstVar(data);
    this.secondVar = this.GetSecondVar(data);
  }

  GetFirstVar(data) {
    var first = data.slice(1, 4).join();
    return first;
  }
  GetSecondVar(data) {
    var cat = data.slice(2, 5);
    return cat;
  }
}

var testData = ['AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB'];
var case1= 0;
var case2= 0;
var caseup=0;

for(let y = 0; y < 10; y++){
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (let i = 0; i < 300000; i++) {
    var testClass = new MyClass(testData);
  }
  
  var stop = new Date().getTime();
  case1 += stop - start;

  start = new Date().getTime();
  for (let i = 0; i < 300000; i++) {
    var testClass = new MyClass2(testData);
  }
  stop = new Date().getTime();
    case2 += stop - start;

  var testClass = new MyClass(testData);
  start = new Date().getTime();
  for (let i = 0; i < 300000; i++) {
    testClass.UpdateClass(testData);
  }
  stop = new Date().getTime();
    caseup += stop - start;
  
}
console.log(`Difference in first case is: ${case1 / 10} ms`)
console.log(`Difference in second case is: ${case2 / 10} ms`)
console.log(`Difference in update case is: ${caseup / 10} ms`)
```

```
Output (3m iterations):
Difference in first case is: 493.4 ms
Difference in second case is: 500.3 ms
Difference in update case is: 469.9 ms
```

So in this simplified version there does appear to be a performance difference for instantiating the class millions of time, but for values orders of magnitudes lower the performance difference becomes less apparent:

```
Output (300k iterations):
Difference in first case is: 49.6 ms
Difference in second case is: 49.1 ms
Difference in update case is: 47 ms
```

EDIT: I added the simple update case and rewrote the test to run ten times and take an average.  Results should be more dependable.

Comment: This is weird, I would have expected the second one to be faster. But not meaningfully either :-) However, to measure performance you should always do this with your real code (which creates 20 properties - performance characteristics for that might be quite different), and more importantly also you need to call the `.UpdateClass` method on its own it that's part of your actual workload. Accessing the class will have a larger impact on performance if the constructor codes really have lead to a different initialisation of properties.

Comment: @Bergi, this is good just to get an idea of how it will all play out, I'll test the real thing privately.  I really appreciate your input.